# How to configure NMAP return also name of device that have SIP port enabled?

Tags: linux, networking, sip, snmp, nmap

What should be command to make NMAP return also name of device connected to the SIP port? I mean to retrieve SNMP device name (sysName.0) system name of the device (router, VoIP, etc) **if** this device have SNMP enabled.

```
nmap -p 5060 -sU -P0 21.12.32.123/24
```

So probably we should also query snmp on all devices it discovers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [snmp-sysdescr](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/snmp-sysdescr.html)

try to combine it with default scriptlike this:

```
sudo nmap  -sU -p 161,5060 --script default,snmp-sysdescr 21.12.32.123/24
```

Note that if your SNMP agents has configured other community then `public` (or in case of v3 similar AUTH mechanism), you need to pass it on command line like this

```
--script-args snmpcommunity=<community string>
```